# How to install localhost by node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

This is the first time to use node.js and I want to run a localhost using node.js server

I actually install node.js, but I don't know how to run localhost server.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Pick a network protocol you want the server to talk. 2. Write JavaScript to listen on an appropriate port and talk that protocol (or find a pre-written library that does it for you).

Comment: Go to [node.js main page](http://nodejs.org) and see the _AN EXAMPLE: WEBSERVER_ example

Comment: a good example is here http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/

Comment: If you can show an example of what you've tried, then others will know more about how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Create the file server.js in the root directory of your project, and fill it with the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Execute your js with

```
node server.js
```

and check on

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: so where is the root folder to put my site files ?